# ASP.NET cannot parse xml! Check file path

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api

I created a simple API via ASP.NET MVC 4:

```
public class ActionController : ApiController
{
    [WebMethod]
    public string getCommunities()
    {
        try
        {
            MethodClass method = new MethodClass();
            return method.getCommunities();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

which is trying to call this method in the Method class:

```
public string getCommunities()
{
    return "bbb";
}
```

but for whatever reason, I get this error:

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">cannot parse xml! Check file path</string>
```

I tried Googling for the error, but came up with nothing, has anyone seen this error before? and how do I fix it?

Comment: WebMethod? Why is it here?

Comment: because I am planning on using this via ajax

Comment: [WebMethod] is not require for MVC applications. Page Methods are old school way of doing in code behind (aspx.cs) pages...

Comment: I tried removing the [WebMethod] still did not work :(

Comment: Have you debugged your application? It seems that the message is rather in the getCommunities() method, where you read the file from somewhere...

Comment: seems like method.getCommunities() is throwing a silent error, double check the method or just try to return a dummy object instead using getcommunities method

Comment: What's happening in the `MethodClass` constructor? I suspect that might be where the `Exception` is thrown...

Comment: Could you please show how are you invoking this method? So we could try to reproduce the problem and help you

Comment: @user979331 I noticed you put a bounty on the question but it's unlikely you receive any better responses than the one you have. Edit the question in order to provide the implementation of GetCommunities() and you might get an answer!

Comment: As suggested could you please share code for MethodClass constructor. and secondly you dont need web method attribute here.

Comment: Who gets the bounty if the problem turns out to be in the MethodClass constructor, as several have suggested?

Comment: Are you doing model binding with XML data in your getCommunities() method ? Because that's one way I could think of XML serialization related errors to occur.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As already pointed in comments, you are looking for your bug in the wrong place. method.getCommunities() is throwing an error with message "cannot parse xml! Check file path".

Googling your [error](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22cannot%20parse%20xml!%20Check%20file%20path%22) it seems to me that you are throwing a custom exception: searching for that string in your code may point you to the right place.

As a quick proof of concept I changed the standard API generated by Visual Studio Web API template.

```
public string Get(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                var t = 0;
                var i = 1 / t;
                return "bbb";
            }
            catch { return "ABBA"; }
        }
```

which exactly returns the custom error message as xml string

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">ABBA</string>
```

Answer (score 2):

I attempted to replicate the case you mention by creating simple `ActionController.cs` in ASP.Net MVC 4 template as follow:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace MvcApiApplicationTrial1.Controllers
{
  public class ActionController : ApiController
  {
    [WebMethod]
    public string getCommunities() {
      try {
        MethodClass method = new MethodClass();
        return method.getCommunities();
      } catch (Exception ex) {
        return ex.Message.ToString();
      }
    }
  }

  public class MethodClass
  {
    public string getCommunities() {
      return "bbb";
    }
  }
}
```

And call it in the web browser (Chrome) with the following url:

```
http://localhost:56491/api/Action/getCommunities
```

And get the following **correct** result:

[image]

If you declare, define, and call things right, your code should have **no** problem at all.

So, I suggest you to re-check your declaration, definition, as well as your calling to the related Controller/Method again. Your problem may lay somewhere else.

And since the error seems to be a custom error, judging from the code posted alone, likely that the problem lays somewhere in your `getCommunities` method. Check the method, try to find the "cannot parse xml!" text there. Alternatively, but less likely, the error is in the `MethodClass` constructor. Same thing, check your `MethodClass`, try to find the "cannot parse xml!" text.

As for the given case as what you have posted in your question, I found no issue at all.

But anything else in between `try` and "bbb" can also potentially be the source of the created error. Checking the error text would be my first step if there are more things in the `try` block and I am unsure where the error may actually be generated.

Answer (score 0):

**in Global.asax.cs should put code bellow:**

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Clear();
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(new System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter());

**and in WebApiConfig code bellow:**

config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/xml"));
var appXmlType = config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.MediaType == "application/xml");